# How to load nested entities without lazy loading in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following model:

```
public class Order 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Number {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> Details {get; set;}
}

public class OrderDetail
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int OrderId {get; set;}
    public virtual Product Product {get; set;}
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Number {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

In my OrderRepository, I load a complete order like this:

```
public override Order Get(int id)
{
    return base.Get(id, x => x.Details);
}
```

And the base method is:

```
public virtual T Get(int id, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] include)
{
    if (include.Any())
    {
        var set = include.Aggregate<Expression<Func<T, object>>, IQueryable<T>>
                  (dbSet, (current, expression) => current.Include(expression));

        return set.SingleOrDefault<T>(x => x.Id == id);
    }

    return dbSet.Find(id);
}
```

The above works partially fine because it loads the Order and the OrderDetails. However, I also want to load the related Product for every Detail so that I can display the product description in the list too.

How can I improve on the above method to allow me to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another argument with nested `Select`:

```
public override Order Get(int id)
{
    return base.Get(id, x => x.Details, x => x.Details.Select(z => z.Product));
}
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#eagerLevels)

Comment: Wow! Couldn't have been easier!!